# Throw error/warning when CreateMap<S, T> is already defined

Tags: c#, automapper

The other day I have been fighting with a non-mapped property by using AutoMapper.

After researching over the application, it ends up being that there was a `CreateMap<S, T>` already defined that was overriding (or reading first) the one that I was trying to configure.

The situation looks like this:

```
public MainProfile()
{
    CreateMap<Class1, Class2>()
        .ForMember(x => x.Property1, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Property1Foo)
        .ForMember(x => x.Property2, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Property2Foo); /*Here is the thing!*/;
}
```

And then there was another class which does the following:

```
public SecondaryProfile()
{
    CreateMap<Class1, Class2>()
        .ForMember(x => x.Property1, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Property1Foo);           
}
```

In my case, when I did:

```
var class2Object = mapper.Map<Class2>(class1Instance);
```

It is taking the definition from `SecondaryProfile.cs` but I was attempting to do it on `MainProfile.cs`, **so the Property2 is not getting mapped.**

This doesn't give you any warning, any error and also compiles fine. On top of that, this can introduce a hard to find bug, so I wonder how can I avoid this situation?

Is there a configuration that you can do to say AutoMapper to warn you on this?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Configuration-validation.html